# Is the Henon attractor connected?

Tags: dynamical-systems

Is it known whether the Henon attractor is connected or not, for the canonical parameters a=1.4 and b=0.3? It certainly appears so, but I haven't seen a proof of this.

Answer (score 0):

The attractor is defined as the closure of the unstable manifold corresponding to the fixed point. Hence it is connected. Furthermore, it then also follows that it has (topological) dimension 1.